# Doubt about integral

Tags: real-analysis

The integral is the next:

$$\int_{\pi}^{-\pi} \int_0^{2}  \theta drd\theta$$
I don't know hoe to convert the integral to Cartesian

Comment: You were on the right track, you were only missing the line $y=-x$. Those three bound this region.

Comment: That comes from $\theta = - \frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Think about what happens to the integrand when you go the other way, from cartesian to polar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\theta$ integration is over a full revolution, so the integration region is a radius-$2$ disc. Since $\theta drd\theta=\frac{\theta}{r}dxdy=\frac{\operatorname{atan2}(y,\,x)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dxdy$, the integral is $-\int_{-2}^2dx\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^\sqrt{4-x^2}\frac{\operatorname{atan2}(y,\,x)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dxdy$. (An earlier version of the question had $\theta$ limits of $\mp\pi/4$, for which the $\pm\sqrt{4-x^2}$ limits become $\max\{\sqrt{4-x^2},\,x\}$, while the lower limit of $x$ changes from $-2$ to $0$; a diagram should convince you of this.) The overall $-$ sign results from the $\theta$ integration going from $\theta=+\pi$ to $\theta=-\pi$; we can absorb it into the Cartesian integral by inverting one of its integration limit pairs.